# Centered Mailchimp embed form disappears when responsive

Tags: html, css, forms, embed, mailchimp

I'm working on a website and I wanted to add a mailchimp subscription form. 
Initially I wanted to use the horizontal form but I was having problems with actually getting peoples mail added to the mailchimp list, and since I didn't want to mess up with any more code I went with the classic from and it's working now but I wanted to centre it and managed to do that by adding  `{margin:0 auto;}`

[image]

The problem now is that in phones or when I minimize my screen it disappears to the left! I don't know how to fix this.

[image]

tho in my file in sublime everything looks so different
[image]

Code:

```
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
  #mc_embed_signup {
    font: 14px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #mce-EMAIL {
    color: #333;
  }
</style>


<div id="homee" class="homepage-hero-module">
  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="title-container">
      <div class="headline">
        <h1>Aumenta tus ingresos usando Facebook<br> para tu negocio</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 lista">
          <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
          <div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form action="//facebook.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=eb920e76ef21ef0d07aca25c8&id=9cbf34e7f5" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
              <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                  <label for="mce-EMAIL"> </label>
                  <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
                </div>
                <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things 
   - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
                  <input type="text" name="b_eb920e76ef21ef0d07aca25c8_9cbf34e7f5" tabindex="-1" value="">
                </div>
                <div class="clear">
                  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```